# i am getting "Expected end of input but got identifier "employee_data" at [9:21]" as a return for a query, what might be the problem

Tags: sql, join

I wrote some SQL code and get this error:

> Expected end of input but got identifier "employee_data" at [9:21]

What might be the problem?

I'm trying to join two databases. They both have different data ids but the query shows syntax error.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    employees.name AS employees_name,
    employeees.role AS employees_role,
    departments.name AS departments_name
FROM 
    employee_data 
INNER JOIN
    department_id ON grand-pact-401713.employee_data.departmental = departments.department_id
```

Comment: What is that `grand-pact-401713.` part supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT
     employees.name AS employees_name,
     employees.role AS employees_role,
     departments.name AS departments_name
 FROM 
     employee_data
 INNER JOIN
     departments ON employee_data.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Here are the changes made:

- Table aliases: You are using aliases for table names (employees, departments), but it seems like there are no aliases defined for these tables. I assumed the table names are employees and departments, so I used these aliases in the corrected query.
- Join condition: The ON clause in the INNER JOIN was incorrect. I assumed that there is a column named department_id in the employee_data table that corresponds to the department_id in the departments table. Adjust this condition based on your actual table structure.

Please replace the table names and join condition with the correct ones from your database schema. Also, make sure that the column names and aliases are spelled correctly to avoid any syntax errors.